# asp.net web api 2 authorize API depending on Entities specific property value(From Database)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-apicontroller

I have made my API's secure using ***Authorize*** attribute.

If the request does not have valid OAuth token, it does not process and returns **authorization error**.

In my User table I have added ***'Status'*** column to check if the user is Active(Soft delete) or not.

I want to use that 'Status' value(Of User Entity) to authenticate my API's.

Suppose Status is false, I want framework should not process the request as like in case 'Authorize attribute'.

- Can it be possible ? If so then How ?

***Note:***

> Now I am checking 'Status' value in my Action and decide to proceed or
>   not.

If you have other best alternatives then those are also welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own AuthorizeAttribute

Here's an example I used to implement my own Authorize method based on Roles:

```
public class AuthorizeRoles : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private readonly List<string> _rolesAllowed;

        public AuthorizeRoles(string rolesAllowed)
        {
            this._rolesAllowed = rolesAllowed.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {            
            var controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller;

                if (!this._rolesAllowed.Contains("*"))
                {
                    string errorMessage = "Authorization denied. Missing required role";
                    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                string errorMessage = "Authorization denied. Request is missing context header";
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }

            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
```

you then use it in your api methods like this :

```
[AuthorizeRoles("some value")] or [AuthorizeRoles("*")]
```

You could effectively specify which methods allow access to people with a certain value in their status.

You have access to the controller, you can check any values you need and allow or deny access based on the results of your check.

I have removed some of my less interesting code but what's left should give you an indication of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it is I would create a Roles table with different access levels. On my controller I would use the Roles feature of the Authorize attribute to allow or block users from accessing the Action.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "isActive")]
```